# jquery - check if query string present on URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible using jquery (or just javascript) to check for the existence of a query string on the URL?

Comment: @Mic - if the question is to be taken literally (just "is it present?"), it's a different question with a much simpler answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, the [`location`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) object has a property [`search`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) that contains the query string.

```
alert(window.location.search);
```

Answer (score 32):

`document.location` contains information about the URL, and `document.location.search` contains the query string, e.g. `?foo=bar&spam=eggs`. As for testing its presence, how about:

```
if(document.location.search.length) {
    // query string exists
} else {
    // no query string exists
}
```

No jQuery required :o

Answer (score 5):

I would think you could use the javascript match operator.

```
var url = window.location.search;
if (url.match("your string").length > 0) {
}
```

Comment: fyi, this is poor because match can return nulls, and putting length of a null object would result in an error

Comment: True. That problem can be solved via something like: `if(url.indexOf("your string") !== -1)`

Answer (score -3):

Check out http://rixi.us/post/791257125/get-and-server-free-dynamic-contet

a method to extract any query string parameters
Use::

```
if (_GET['key']) {
  var key = _GET['key']
}
```

Comment: -1. OP specified jQuery (or Javascript) not PHP as the language they are using.

Comment: @theringostarrs It actually is not PHP, it is just a small amount of javascript that I wrote a long while back that allows you to extract GET variables from the URL. Vastly outdated, and I'm not sure that link works anymore, but it is/was Javascript.

Comment: Why did you mix JavaScript and PHP in literally the same if-block on a JavaScript question